# How to find records of a column if the data type of a column has been changed using a where condition

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

To know what the data types of the columns in a table are, we use `'desc schema.table_name'`. If a particular column's data type has been changed from `character` to `numeric`.

How do I check if there are any records in that table with the data type character.

I see `Select distinct column_1 from schema.table_name` gives all the distinct values in that column

BUT Can we check if a data type of `'character'` got into this table using a `where` condition?

Answer (score 0):

If understand you correctly you probably want to use [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) in MySql

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1
 WHERE column1 NOT REGEXP '^[0-9]+$'
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/25ce7/2)** (MySql)

And [`REGEXP_LIKE`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/conditions007.htm) if it's Oracle

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1
 WHERE NOT REGEXP_LIKE(column1, '^[0-9]+$')
```

or without `REGEXP_LIKE`

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table1
 WHERE LENGTH(TRIM(TRANSLATE (column1, '0123456789',' ')))  IS NOT NULL
```

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f6ecb/10)** (Oracle 11g)

Comment: I am using an Oracle client and it says REGEXP is an invalid relational operator

Comment: Are you using MySql or Oracle RDBMS?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Sql. You can use this query.

```
select column_name from table_name where column_name not like [0-9]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query if you are using oracle server

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE  regexp_like(column_name,'[^0-9]+')
```

Comment: Im using Oracle 11g client and it throws an error after the where condition

Comment: I have run this query in oracle 11g and its working fine for me. What error exactly are you getting?